# Set variable if doesn't exist from class

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to do an if then for some required vars, that if no value is provided, set a default value:

```
slaveCpus = Globals."SLAVE_${i}_CPU" ?: '0.1',

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: SLAVE_1_CPU for class: Globals
```

Comment: Globals class should have a property named SLAVE_1_CPU. Using Globals."SLAVE_${i}_CPU", you are trying to access properties dynamically. But to access them they should exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following your question correctly, you'd like to add dynamic static properties to Globals with a default value of 0.1.

This can be achieved by adding a static, `$static_propertyMissing` method to the Globals class:

```
class Globals {
    static double SLAVE_1_CPU = 1.0
    static double SLAVE_2_CPU = 2.0

    static $static_propertyMissing(String name) {
        0.1 
    } 
}
```

If you can't change the Globals source code, you can also use meta-programming to add the method:

```
Globals.metaClass.static.propertyMissing << { name -> 0.1 }
```

With either approach,

```
(1..3).each { i ->
    println Globals."SLAVE_${i}_CPU"
}
```

prints out

```
1.0
2.0 
0.1
```